# How To change default Browser?

Tags: web-browser

Everything I open will open in this cretain of a browser called Epiphany. Discord, Thunderbird, etc.. all Links open a new instance or tab in Epiphany. I do want to open everything only in Firefox. I can't be the only one. How to mitigate this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `System Settings` > `Applications` > `Default` Tab. There you can set your default web browser, email client, text editor etc.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In some instances, the program you want to define as default does not appear on its category menu drop-down in `System Settings > Applications > Default tab`

Another way is to right click on a file with an extension (for a web browser, that would be a `.html` file), and set the program to be used in Properties.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be set directly from a terminal with the `xdg-settings` command.
Just provide file name of the `.desktop` file for the browser, often available in `/usr/share/applications` or in `~/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share/applications/` if the browser was installed as a Flatpak.
For instance, to set the default web browser to Firefox, assuming it's installed of course, just use the following command.

```
$ xdg-settings set default-web-browser firefox.desktop
```